# Form to make URL - Simple product chooser

Tags: forms, url, submit, selector, silverstripe

I've created a products and services folders and items in SilverStripe CMS and everything is fine with it but I'd like to have a kind of product chooser.

I thought that I can make it through the form by drop-downs and when you will choose value 1 then you can pick from value 2 but what's the most important is when you click on submit I would like the form to construct a link/ url like: http://www.example.com/value1/value2 and automaticaly go there.

Simple: let's assume that I have upper section (called SAMSUNG) then inside of it I've products/ child pages (for example: Galaxy S3, Galaxy S4, Galaxy S5, etc.) and I want people to choose using this simple form: first choose manufacturer -> device type/ model/ name -> click submit (go) and it will take you directly to the right place: http://www.example.com/manufacturer/product

Is it possible to get URL like that through the form?

Answer (score 0):

This would be easy enough. Basically what you want to do is have your form submit somewhere, then redirect to the desired URL using the submitted data from there.

**In some controller**

```
private static $allowed_actions = array(
    'Form'
);

public function Form() {
    $fields = new FieldList(
        new DropdownField('Manufacturer', 'Manufacturer', array(
            'Samsumg' => 'Samsumg',
            'HTC' => 'HTC',
            'Apple' => 'Apple'
        )),
        // It's necessary that first argument is Samsung as it will
        // be used to fetch the device later on
        new DropdownField('Samsumg', 'Samsumg', array(
            'GalaxyS3' => 'Galaxy S3',
            'GalaxyS4' => 'Galaxy S4',
            'GalaxyS5' => 'Galaxy S5'
        )),
        // It's necessary that first argument is HTC as it will
        // be used to fetch the device later on
        new DropdownField('HTC', 'HTC', array(
            'Desire' => 'Desire',
            'Wildfire' => 'Wildfire',
            'One' => 'One'
        )),
        // It's necessary that first argument is Apple as it will
        // be used to fetch the device later on
        new DropdownField('Apple', 'Apple', array(
            'iPhne5' => 'iPhone 5',
            'iPhone6' => 'iPhone 6',
            'iPhone6Plus' => 'iPhone 6 Plus'
        ))
    );

    $actions = new FieldList(
        new FormAction('submit', 'Search')
    );

    return new Form($this, 'Form', $fields, $actions);
}

public function submit($data, $form) {
    // Get selected manufacturer
    $manufacturer = $data['Manufacturer'];

    // Get selected device by selected manufacturer
    $device = $data[$manufacturer];

    // Redirect to the manufacturer/device URL
    return $this->redirect($manufacturer . '/' . $device);
}
```

Output the form by using `$Form` in your template.